# how to store mongodb query result in a global variable in node js

Tags: node.js

I have written below code in NodeJS which fetches data from MongboDB with certain criteria:

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var Employee = require('Employee');
    var emp = {};
    var csv = require('csv-express');
    emp.ply = function(res,res) { Employee.find({area:  
    'Plymouth'}).exec(function(err,PLY) {res.render("../index", 
    {resultset: PLY})
    }
   };

  emp.export = function(req,res) {
  var filename = 'Exportlist.csv';
  var dataArray;
  Employee.find({}).lean().exec(function (err, employees) { res.csv(employees,true); };};
```

Now I want to store the above query result into some variable and want to export only those set of data instead of entire database. Please suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: inside query callback function do: dataArray.push(employees);

Comment: Hi Luca,  in my code i'm doing query to find out the records where area is Plymouth. In later code im doing export of all the records by doing blank query. Now instead of doing export of all records i want to export only records which I found in earlier query where area is Plymouth. It means I want to leverage resultset of query and send the output to export. I believe this will give more clarity on my requirement.